# Adding a vue component results in 'parentNode' TypeError

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vue-component

I have a page that is only partially rendering. The page renders Listings but not Bookings. I have tried removing the divs that are coupled to `isReviewed()` and then the page renders normally. Somehow the component is causing an error.

```
<template>
<div>
  <p><router-link to="start">ClearBnB</router-link></p>
  <Navbar />
  <p>Profile page for {{ username }}</p>
  <hr>
  <h2>Listings</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="listing in listings" v-bind:key="listing.listing_id">
      <img :src="listing.image_url" width="300" alt="listed property" />
      <h3>{{ listing.title }}</h3>
      <p><strong>{{ listing.location }}</strong></p>
      <p>{{ listing.price }} €</p>
      <p>Guests: {{ listing.guests }}</p>
      <p>
        Available:
        {{ formatDate(listing.start) }} ― {{ formatDate(listing.end) }}
      </p>
      <p>
        <br /><br />
        {{ listing.description }}
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <hr>
  <h2>Bookings</h2>
  <ol>
    <li v-for="booking in bookings" v-bind:key="booking.booking_id">
      <p><strong> {{ getTitle(booking.listing_id) }} </strong></p>
      <img :src="getImage(booking.listing_id)" width="150" alt="booked property" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <p v-if="booking.cancelled" style="color: red">CANCELLED</p>
      Guests: {{ booking.guests }}
      <br>
      <p>Fee: {{ booking.fee }}</p>
      {{ formatDate(booking.start) }} ― {{ formatDate(booking.end )}}
      <br><br>
      <div v-if="!isReviewed()">
        <textarea rows="8" cols="35" name="comment" placeholder="Add review"/>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="rating" placeholder="Rating (1-5)" size="5" maxlength="1"/>
        <br><br>
        <button type="button">Add Review</button>
        <br><br>
      </div>
      <div v-if="isReviewed()">
        <ReviewItem v-bind:comment="comment" v-bind:rating="rating" />
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar.vue";
import ReviewItem from "../components/ReviewItem.vue";

export default {
  name: 'MyProfile',
  components: { Navbar, ReviewItem },
  data() {
    return {
      username: "",
      userId: "",
      listings: [],
      bookings: [],
      bookedListings: [],
      comment: "test comment parent",
      rating: [],
      }
  },
  async created() {
    
    this.username = this.$store.getters.getUser.username;
    this.userId = this.$store.getters.getUserId;
    
    // Get listings
    this.listings = await (await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/user-listings/' + this.userId)).json();

    // Get bookings
    this.bookings = await (await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/user-bookings/' + this.userId)).json();

    // Get booked listings
    let listingId;
    for (let booking of this.bookings) {
      listingId = booking.listing_id;
      this.bookedListings.push({id: listingId, listing: await (await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/listing/' + listingId)).json()});
      console.log('pushed 1 listing onto bookedListings')
    }
    console.log('this.bookedListings ', this.bookedListings);
  },
  methods: {
    isReviewed() {
      return true;
    },
    formatDate(date) {
      date = new Date(date);
      let month;
      if (date.getMonth().toString().length === 1) {
        month = '0' + date.getMonth();
      } else {
        month = date.getMonth().toString();
      }
      let day;
      if (date.getDay().toString().length === 1) {
        day = '0' + date.getDay();
      } else {
        day = date.getDay();
      }
      date = date.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day;
      return date;
    },
    getTitle(listingId) {
      let listing = this.bookedListings.find(currentListing => currentListing.id === listingId).listing;
      return listing.title;
    },
    getImage(listingId) {
      let listing = this.bookedListings.find(currentListing => currentListing.id === listingId).listing;
      return listing.image_url;
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

When adding this component:

```
<template>
  <p>Review</p>
  <p v-bind="comment" class="review"></p>
  <p>Rating: <span v-for="star in rating" v-bind:key="star">⭐</span></p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ReviewItem',
  props: ['rating', 'comment'],
data() {
  return {
    rating: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    comment: 'test comment',
  }
}
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')
    at parentNode (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:36)
    at patchBlockChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4087)
    at patchElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4055)
    at processElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3871)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3788)
    at patchBlockChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4091)
    at patchElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4055)
    at processElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3871)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3788)
    at patchKeyedChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4506)
```

Somehow vue registers the parentNode as null and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add an empty components part to the component. Apparently these must be defined:

```
  components: {},
```